# How to Uninstall a Python package without pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can we uninstall a python package without PIP on Unix and Windows?

Version: Python3.x and above.

Comment: Was the package installed with `pip` originally? Why not use `pip`?

Comment: As a side note -- this is a good reason to use virtual environments. Instead of uninstalling packages, simply delete the virtual env and all packages will be removed.

Comment: Agreed @TeejayBruno. The issue is that PYTZ package got currupted (Missing timezones) and i need to re-install it. The issue is that we need to install/uninstall it manually and there is no commands I know of to do so without PIP.

Comment: @Chris_Rands because the server is enclosed on a private network with very strict firewall rules. This box doesn't connect to public internet making pip not usable.

Comment: Also @Chris_Rands because the package wasn't install with PIP.  PIP can't delete the package (Error: "It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot ........." )

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use another package manager such as `conda`. This will only work if the package was originally installed with that package manager.
2. Delete the package manually with File Explorer or the command-line.

Comment: Do you have the exact command on how to do it in command-line?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the package files manually using Windows explorer, or any Linux file manager, or through command line. In Linux packages are in `/lib/site-packages/` and in Windows get them in installation directiory somewhere.

Comment: Oh! so just doing "rm-f" on the package directory will delete it? (Unix perspective).

Comment: It will delete it but depending on the package, it may have added dependencies elsewhere.